# Notation D.J Saunders 's book (The geometry of jet bundles)

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, fiber-bundles, jet-bundles

in D.J Saunders 's book (The geometry of jet bundles) on page 25 he defines the vertical bundle by :

Given the bundle $(E,\pi,M)$ the subset
$$\{\xi \in TE:\pi_*(\xi)=0 \in TM\}$$
is called the set of vectors vertical to $\pi$. It is denoted $V\pi$ and is a submanifold of $TE$.

The triple $(V\pi,\tau_E|_{V\pi},E)$ is a sub-bundle of $\tau_E$ which is called the
vertical bundle to $\pi$.

Where $\tau_E:TE\rightarrow E$ denote the map which associates to
each tangent vector the point of $E$ at which it is located.

Now on page 125 he introduces this bundle $(V\pi,\nu_\pi,M)$
Could any one explain me how this bundle is defined ?

Comment: Possibly the projection $V\pi\to E\to M$? ie here the bundle has fibre $(V\pi)\lvert_{\pi^{-1}(x)}$

Comment: that was what i suspected